# StackStats Chrome Extension (placeholder)

Tags: app, placeholder

#### About:

Whether you want to keep track of your statistics or watch for an update on a post you've made, you'll be able to do it all with ***StackStats***.

Currently in development, but would love to hear some ideas about features that could be included. If you submit a feature (by replying to this post) it will be reviewed and if deemed useful by me or the community I will add it to the feature list.

###### Current & Upcoming Features Include:

1. **CURRENT**: Fully modular and customizable feature watch list that updates in real time
2. **CURRENT**: (*There will be many more options in future*) Ability to watch:

   - Unread inbox
   - Unread notifications
   - Reputation
   - Badges
   - Question count
   - Answer count
   - Comment count
   - Up vote count
   - Down vote count
3. **UPCOMING**: Filter inbox notifications to posts made in specific tags, with specific URL's and/or specific users
4. **UPCOMING**: Watch stats for specific network, or stats for all networks a user has joined
5. **UPCOMING**: Add option to send push notifications/extension icon changes when a configured value changes (e.g. post or inbox notification)
6. **UPCOMING**: Add user profile picture, rep and badges graphic

[image]

#### Download / Install:

Since it is currently in development, there is no official download link currently. Once a version of StackStats is deemed ready it will be released onto the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) where users can download it.

#### Platform:

This is available for all users of Chrome Extension supporting browsers such as:

- Google Chrome
- Brave Browser
- Chromium (for linux users)
- Opera GX
- Microsoft Edge

#### Contact:

I am the sole developer at the moment.
You can find me here on the network, through my Discord (`joE#3011`), or through [Github](https://github.com/meropis). Ideally feature requests/proposals and discussion would go in the comments and answers to this post.

#### License:

No license as of yet. The extension will be free. Permanently.

#### Code:

I have used TypeScript and React to create this extension, making it both fast and type safe. I have a private Github repository I am using for development that I will make public once I have made more progress.

If you're interested in contributing, don't hesitate to get in contact with me.